# How do I use Microsoft's Push Notification Service in a PhoneGap app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working on a PhoneGap App (for WP7) that needs to register with Microsoft's Push Notification Service. I can't seem to find any plugins for WP7 like there are for Android / iOS.

Is it possible to create a HttpNotificationChannel object and event listeners in App.xaml.cs, and somehow alert the JavaScript code when a notification is received?

Comment: I dont know for WP7 but for WP8, there is this official plugin: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Answer (score 0):

Push Notification  Plugin support for PhoneGap build has been promised for more than a year. You can check this out from 2011 : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/glengordon/archive/2011/11/15/phonegap-on-windows-phone-tips.aspx

Three months ago in the Phonegap community it was still described as something that would be supported in the future. I have been checking out release notes but found nothing mentioning this feature: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/_phonegap_build_future_plugin_support?page=1

So unfortunately it still doesn't support Push Notification yet.

Comment: @Arslan, you're being discussed [over on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142887/spam-edit-approved).

Comment: I see your point about PhoneGap not supporting Push Notifs for WP7. My question was if there's any way to get a Notification Channel open in C# and then interact with the JS code.

Comment: i mean it was did't have  surrpot package. i can be interact with javascript code。